# Use QR factorizations to find intersection of two planes

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

This question is Problem $7.4$ in *Numerical Linear Algebra* by Lloyd N. Trefethen and David Bau, III.

> **Problem $7.4$:** Let $\newcommand{\1}{^{(1)}}
> \newcommand{\2}{^{(2)}}
> \newcommand{\ip}[1]{\left \langle #1 \right \rangle}
> x\1,y\1,x\2,$ and $y\2$ be nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the property that $x\1$ and $y\1$ are linearly independent and so are $x\2$ and $y\2$. Consider the two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$,
> $$
> P\1 = \ip{x\1,y\1} \qquad P\2 = \ip{x\2,y\2}
> $$
> Suppose we wish to find a nonzero vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ which lies in the intersection of the planes, $P = P\1 \cap P\2$, the intersection of the planes. Devise a method for solving this problem by reducing it to the computation of the QR factorizations of three $3 \times 2$ matrices.

I can numerically compute the $QR$ factorization but I don't see how I could find the three matrices and how that would help me find the intersection of $P^{(1)}$ and $P^{(2)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider matrices $\newcommand{\nc}{\newcommand}
\nc{\para}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
\nc{\abs}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}
\nc{\br}[1]{\left[ #1 \right]}
\nc{\set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}
\nc{\ip}[1]{\left \langle #1 \right \rangle}
\nc{\n}[1]{\left\| #1 \right\|}
\nc{\norm}[1]{\left\| #1 \right\|}
\nc{\floor}[1]{\left \lfloor #1 \right \rfloor}
\nc{\ceil}[1]{\left \lceil #1 \right \rceil}
\nc{\setb}[2]{\set{#1 \, \middle| \, #2}}
\nc{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\nc{\dv}[2]{\frac{\dd #1}{\dd #2}}
\nc{\p}{\partial}
\nc{\pdv}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\nc{\a}{\alpha}
\nc{\b}{\beta}
\nc{\g}{\gamma}
\nc{\d}{\delta}
\nc{\ve}{\varepsilon}
\nc{\t}{\theta}
\nc{\m}[1]{\begin{bmatrix} #1 \end{bmatrix}}
\nc{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\nc{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\nc{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\nc{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
\nc{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\nc{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\nc{\AA}{\mathcal{A}}
\nc{\BB}{\mathcal{B}}
\nc{\CC}{\mathcal{C}}
\nc{\FF}{\mathcal{F}}
\nc{\GG}{\mathcal{G}}
\nc{\II}{\mathcal{I}}
\nc{\JJ}{\mathcal{J}}
\nc{\KK}{\mathcal{K}}
\nc{\PP}{\mathcal{P}}
\nc{\RR}{\mathcal{R}}
\nc{\SS}{\mathcal{S}}
\nc{\TT}{\mathcal{T}}
\nc{\1}{^{(1)}}
\nc{\2}{^{(2)}}
\nc{\i}{^{(i)}}
M\1,M\2$ where
$$
M\i := \br{ x\i \, \middle| \, y\i } 
$$
and generate corresponding full QR factorizations $M\i = Q\i R\i$.

Recall that $M\i \in \C^{3 \times 2}$, so in the QR factorization, for $Q\i$ to be square, it needs to be "padded out" with an additional column (one that is missing from the other two one would find in the reduced QR factorization via, say, Gram-Schmidt).

Call this extra column  $q\i$. By the orthogonality of the other two, it holds that $q\i \perp P\i$. Form a new matrix,
$$
\widetilde{M} := \br{ q\1 \, \middle| \, q\2 }
$$
Each column is a unit normal for its respective plane. Of course, this matrix also has a full QR factorization, $\widetilde{M} = \widetilde{Q} \widetilde{R}$. If a vector $v$ lies in $P\1 \cap P\2$, it must be perpendicular to the normals of both planes, to the first two columns of $\widetilde{Q}$.

It is then easy to see that the line containing $v$ must be perpendicular to those columns - hence, in the span of third column of $\widetilde{Q}$.